# Use OpenCL on AMD APU but use discrete GPU for the X server

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, amd-processor

Is it possible to enable OpenCL on an A10-7800 without using it for the X server?  I have a Linux box that I use for GPGPU programming.  A discrete GEForce 740 card is used for both the X server and running OpenCL & Cuda programs I develop. I would also like the option of running OpenCL code on the APU's integrated GPU cores.

Everything I've read so far implies that if I want to use the APU for OpenCL, I have to install Catalyst and, AFAIK, that means using it for the X server.  Is this true?  Would there be an advantage to using the APU for my X server and using the GEForce solely for GPGPU code?

Comment: If x server is 64 bit, you could try 32 bit driver for APU so it is not seen by x-server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar goal, so I've built a system with AMD APU (4 regular cores + 6 GPUs) and Nvidia discrete graphics board. Sorry to say it wasn't easy to make it work, so I asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747581/the-amd-fglrx-driver-doesnt-see-gpu-cores-in-amd-apu-a8-7600) on the `Ask Ubuntu` forum, didn't get any answers, experimented a lot with hardware and software setup, and finally have posted my own answer to my question.

I'll describe my setup again here - who knows, what might happen with my auto-answered question on the `Ask Ubuntu`?

At first, I had to enable the integrated graphics hardware via a BIOS flag. This flag is called `IGFX Multi-Monitor` on my motherboard (ASUS A88X-PRO).

The second step was to find a right mix of a low-level graphics driver and high-level OpenCL implementation. The low-level driver for AMD processors is called `AMD Catalyst` and has a file name `fglrx`. I didn't install this driver from the Ubuntu software center - instead I used a version `15.302`, directly downloaded from the AMD site. I had to install a significant number of prerequisites for this driver. The most important finding was that I had to *skip* running the `aticonfig` command after the `fglrx` installation - this command actually configures the X server to use *this* driver for graphics output, and I didn't want that.

Then I've installed the AMD SDK Ver 3.0 (release 130.136, earlier releases didn't work with my `fglrx`) - it's the OpenCL implementation from AMD. The `clinfo` command reports both CPUs and GPUs with correct number of cores now.

So, I have a hybrid AMD processor, supported by the OpenCL, with all the graphics output, supported by a discrete graphics card with Nvidia processor.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Your situation closely mirrors mine and the information you provided will certainly get me further down the road when I try it out.  Or else get me in deeper over my head! :)

Comment: Finally got around to trying HEKTO's advice and got close.  Very close.  When I boot, I can run clinfo and it reports that there are two platforms available - the NVidia card and the APU.  But subsequent attempts to run clinfo or oclDeviceQuery result in a segfault.

Searching the web shows that this may be a known issue.  I'm sure it isn't helped that I'm running Linux Mint, which isn't really a supported platform for what I want to do but the fact that I'm close gives me hope.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a Linux server (OpenSUSE, but the distribution shouldn't matter) containing both NVIDIA and (a discrete) AMD GPU.  It's headless, so technically I do not know whether the X server will create additional problems, but I don't think so.  You can always configure xorg.conf to use exactly the driver you want.  Or for that matter: install Catalyst, but delete the X server driver file itself, which is *not* the same thing that you need for OpenCL.

There is one problem with a mixed-vendor system that I noticed, however: AMDs OpenCL driver (ICD) will go spelunking for a libGL.so library, I guess in order to do OpenCL/OpenGL-interop.  If it finds any of the NVIDIA-supplied libGL.so's, it will get confused and hang - at least on my machine.  I "solved" this by deleting all libGL.so's (I do not need it on a headless compute server), but that might not be an acceptable solution for you.  Maybe you can arrange things such that the AMD-supplied libGL.so's take precedence, possibly by installing the AMD driver last.